# std::exchange working differently with VC++ and gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++

following code:

```cpp
#include <utility>

int main()
{
  auto pos = 0;
  auto rel = pos - std::exchange(pos, pos + 1);

  return rel; // g++: 0, VC++: 1
}
```

If you try the code on [rextester](https://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual) with the VC++ compiler then the result is 1, with gcc on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/jdxKnE) the result is 0 (results are apparently not returned with gcc using rextester).

**Question**: Why are the results different?

And **2nd question**: Are there any tools to check for that mistake? Any clang warnings?

My guess is that `std::exchange` in VC++ is called *before* the other operand is evaluated, whereas in gcc this is not the case. If you swap the operands `pos` and `std::exchange` the result is -1 (or 255) both VC++ and with gcc.

It is probably something about side effects - and calling `std::exchange` which clearly has a side-effect.

Fortunately I caught the bug with a unit test after transitioning from VC++ to gcc - and was a bit flustered at first and boiled it down to this simple (not) working example.

Comment: Sounds like undefined behaviour to me. There's no requirement that they're evaluated left to right.

Comment: @tadman and your comment is helpful how exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Binary operator `-` is note associated with a [sequence point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point), meaning it is not specified in which order expressions `A` and `B` will be evaluated in `A - B`:

> Consider two functions `f()` and `g()`. In C and C++, the `+` operator is not associated with a sequence point, and therefore in the expression `f()+g()` it is possible that either `f()` or `g()` will be executed first. [...] In C and C++, evaluating such an expression yields undefined behavior.[

Thus, your program have undefined behaviour, and any analysis of cross-compiler behaviour is futile.

---

In standardese, this is [[intro.execution]/17](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.execution#17) [**emphasis** mine]:

> Except where noted, **evaluations of operands of individual
> operators** and of subexpressions of individual expressions **are
> unsequenced**. [ *Note:* In an expression that is evaluated more than
> once during the execution of a program, unsequenced and
> indeterminately sequenced evaluations of its subexpressions need not
> be performed consistently in different evaluations.  — *end note* ]
> The value computations of the operands of an operator are sequenced
> before the value computation of the result of the operator. **If a
> side effect on a memory location is unsequenced relative to** either
> another side effect on the same memory location or **a value
> computation using the value of any object in the same memory
> location**, and they are not potentially concurrent, **the behavior is
> undefined**. [ *Note:* The next section imposes similar, but more
> complex restrictions on potentially concurrent computations.  — *end
> note* ]
>
> [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> void g(int i) {
>   i = 7, i++, i++;  // i becomes 9
>
>   i = i++ + 1;      // the value of i is incremented
>   i = i++ + i;      // the behavior is undefined
>   i = i + 1;        // the value of i is incremented
> }
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

Comment: I get the point - so: basically never use code with side effects in an expression with binary (or any?) operators. It would be nice to have compile warnings for that.

Comment: @michael_s Compiler vendors typically focus (given the complexity of the language) on implementing diagnostics as required by the standard. A good static analysis tool may be able to warn you about cases as your own, though.

Comment: I don't see undefined behavior. The body of the function is sequenced before the evaluation of the expression. The order in which the sub-expressions are evaluated is unspecified, but not undefined.

Comment: @j6t Whilst the order of in which the sub-expressions are evaluated is unspecified, if I am not mistaken, [\[intro.execution\]/17](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.execution#17) applies here, as one of the sub-expressions have side effects on the same memory location that another sub-expression reads ("value computation"), and OP:s example is undefined?

Comment: Yes, it applies. But still, the modification happens inside `exchange` and that is sequenced before the value computation of the function call. But now I am unsure whether this gives any additional guarantees. Note that the side-effects that [intro.execution]/17 talks about are those of the operators in the expressions. Side-effects that happen inside invoked functions do not count. The OP's example has side-effects only in the assignment.

Comment: @j6t it looks like there's really no UB. But the result is still unspecified. ICC also results in 1 https://godbolt.org/z/zvvbx5

Comment: After reading [intro.execution/18](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.execution#18), I am convinced that it is unspecified behavior, not undefined.

Comment: @j6t My interpretation of [intro.execution]/18 is that the modification inside the `exchange` function is sequenced **after** value computations and side effects associated with any argument expression _used in the call to `exchange`_. Denote this sequencing as `{argument expressions to exchange (pos, pos+1) >>sequence next>> modification in exchange}`. This whole expression, say `{B}`, is however unsequenced w.r.t. the _other operand for the operator call_, say `{value compute pos}`, such that `{value compute pos} - {B}`, is unsequenced, and [intro.execution]/17 applies such that there is UB.

Comment: @j6t Finally note that there is a difference here between different operators as of [P0145R3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0145r3.pdf) which was implemented for C++17, and we have a particular example of it in [\[expr.call\]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.call#5). P0145R3 never applied for binary arithmetic operators, however, so the OP:s example is still undefined,  afaict.

Comment: But [intro.execution/18](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.execution#18) says: *For each function invocation F, for every evaluation A that occurs within F and every evaluation B that does not occur within F [...], either A is sequenced before B or B is sequenced before A.* Therefore, the evaluation of `pos` outside the `exchange` sub-expression is indeterminately sequenced with the body of `exchange`, hence, we have unspecified behavior, not undefined behavior.

Comment: @j6t I'm not conviced: /18 applies for single function call w.r.t. its respective arguments, but you seem to apply that paragraph to also place sequencing guarantees between _between_ arguments of one function call (here: the operator- call) based on the fact that on of the arguments itself is a function call. But these are different levels, afaict, and when we are considering the operator call, its two arguments are unsequenced and both fall under /17, such it should be no different from  the example of /17 (where operator++ is the nested call of one argument to operator+). ...

Comment: ... Or, in code, consider [the following snippet](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jQ2LhoQLYxToVr0d), where as per (the explicit example of) [intro.execution]/17, `auto a = i++ + i;` _is_ UB (no question about that, right?); then why would the cases for `b` through `e` be any different?

Comment: Cases a and b are *very* different, because all operations in `f++ + f` are function calls, and so the arguments are indeterminately sequenced (since C++17). We have unspecified behavior (since C++17), not undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

["Undefined behaviour"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) is an extremely important principle to understand. If you haven't learned about it yet, that's something you have an opportunity to address now. If behaviour is not *specifically defined*, then it's *undefined*, meaning weird things like this can and will happen.

For a given expression `a - f(a)` there is absolutely no requirement that the compiler execute in left to right order. The defined behaviour only states that the outcome represents both `a` and `f(a)` as evaluated independently first.

If you want your program to produce *consistent, correct* results then one of the challenges is to avoid undefined behaviour. How do you do this? The compiler won't tell you when you do it, it will happen silently, and it might even "work" under all the conditions you use the code.

If you want it to be truly correct you need to know a multitude of rules like this one where the behaviour is undefined and you just need to respect that. There's really no way around it. Like when dealing with iterator invalidation, free after use, and use of uninitialized variables, you have considerable responsibility to code things correctly. This is why C++ can be exceptionally challenging to code correctly.

In summary, other languages make specific guarantees about the order of execution in an expression like this. C++ does not.